# How can i show data into bootstrap panel dynamically by javascript?

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, asp.net-mvc

How can show data into bootstrap panel dynamically when i click any panel?When i clicked each of a panel that data showed only into first panel.

index

```
 <div class="panel panel-info class" style="height: 450px; width: 300px; overflow-y:scroll;">
       @foreach (var item in lstCategory)
       {
            <div class="panel-heading" id="panel-heading">
                <h4 class="panel-title">
                    <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="collapse(@item.Id);" data-parent="#accordion" href="#@item.Id">@item.Name</a>
                </h4>
        </div>

       <div id="@item.Id" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
           <div id="file">
           </div>
        </div>

       }

</div>
```

javascript

```
   function collapse(id) {
    var id = id;

                $.ajax({
                    type: "GET",
                    url: "/Document/GetFileList",
                    data:{id:id},
                    success: function (response) {
                        //var panelbar = $find("<%= %>");
                        $("#file").html(response);


                    }
                });
}
```

[image]
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line on your javascript code adds everything on the same div, even if you have multiple divs, because you do not distinct the id of each div.

```
$("#file").html(response);
```

The solution is to add different ids on each div using the `@item.Id` and then use that id to add the correct content on the correct id.

Eg add the id on the div

```
<div id="file_@item.Id">
</div>
```

then on javascript use the id to find that div.

```
function collapse(id) {
    var id = id;
    $.ajax({
        type: "GET",
        url: "/Document/GetFileList",
        data:{id:id},
        success: function (response) {
            $("#file_" + id).html(response);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: Aristos, can u tell me how can i get expanded panel value/id/name? I tried but getting alws first panel name/id.

        <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="collapse(@item.Id);" name="@item.Name"  id="collapse" href="#@item.Id">@item.Name</a>
        
var panelId = $(".collapse").attr("name");

Comment: @MehediIslam this is a different question, you must act similar with this one

Comment: Aristos,i already post this type problem that i could not solve.If u see this  and solve this it will be help for me.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38716995/how-can-i-get-name-id-of-a-expanded-panel-from-a-dynamic-panel-list-by-javascrip?noredirect=1#comment64810488_38716995

Answer (score 1):

It's because you are injecting the response of the ajax call into the div with the id of file, which will always add it to that first panel. Try adding a class to the file div which is constructed from the id and then inject into that element instead. something like...

```
<div class="file_@item.Id"></div>
```

and then do

```
$(".file_" + id).html(response);
```

in your success callback

Comment: Hi Bencrinkle, can u tell me how can i get expanded panel value/id/name? I tried but getting alws first panel name/id. <a data-toggle="collapse" onclick="collapse(@item.Id);" name="@item.Name" id="collapse" href="#@item.Id">@item.Name</a> var panelId = $(".collapse").attr("name");