# Show data from MySQL into bootstrap modal (no ajax)

Tags: php, mysql, database, modal-dialog, bootstrap-modal

In my page, I have a list of shops with some information. For each shop, I have a button that opens a modal where I want to show all the information about the shop.

I put my modal inside the while that generates the list and the first result is correctly shown into the modal, but if I click the second, third etc... shop in the list, I see the information about the first shop (now I tried only with the name of the shop). I don't understand why.

Is it possible for each store to show its information? Is it mandatory to use ajax?

I check this question [How can i show data into bootstrap panel dynamically by javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38692859/how-can-i-show-data-into-bootstrap-panel-dynamically-by-javascript) but it didn't helped me.

This is the code with the php that generates my list, the button that opens the modal, and the modal:

```
<?php
    echo'<section class="col-xs-12 col-sm-6 col-md-12">';
    $sql = "SELECT nome_L, tipocucina_TC, wifi_L, tipolocale_TL, descrizione_L, indirizzo_L, fasciaprezzo_L, convenzione_L, image_thumb_L  FROM locale l 
            JOIN tipocucina c On l.TipoCucina_L = c.IDtipocucina_TC
            JOIN tipolocale t On l.TipoLocale_L = t.IDTipolocale_TL
            WHERE TRUE";

    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die(mysqli_error($conn));

    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) 
    {
        $nome_Local = $row['nome_L'];
        $descrizione_Local = $row['descrizione_L'];
        $indirizzo_Local = $row['indirizzo_L'];
        $tipocucina_Local = $row['tipocucina_TC'];
        $tipolocale_Local = $row['tipolocale_TL'];
        $immagine_Local = $row['image_thumb_L'];

        //START MODAL
        echo'
            <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
                <div class="modal-dialog">
                    <div class="modal-content">
                        <div class="modal-header">
                            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">&times;</button>
                            <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">'.$nome_Local.'</h4>
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-body">
                        ...
                        </div>
                        <div class="modal-footer">

                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        ';
        //END MODAL

        echo'<article class="search-result row">
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                    <a href="#" title="Lorem ipsum" class="thumbnail"><img src="images/locals/'.$immagine_Local.'"/></a>
                </div>
                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-2" style="width: 18%;">
                    <ul class="meta-search">
                        <li><i class="fa fa-cutlery fa-lg"></i> <span>'.$tipocucina_Local.'</span></li>
                        <li><i class="fa fa-coffee fa-lg"></i> <span>'.$tipolocale_Local.'</span></li>
                    </ul>
                </div>

                <div class="col-xs-12 col-sm-12 col-md-7 excerpet" style="width: 55%;">';
                    echo"<h3><a>".$nome_Local."</a></h3>";
                    echo'<i class="fa fa-compass"> </i>'.$indirizzo_Local.'</i>';
                    echo"<br>";
                    echo'<p class="local-description">'.$descrizione_Local.'</p>';   

                    //BUTTON THAT OPEN MY MODAL
                    echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Show more </button>'; 
                    echo'
                </div>
                <span class="clearfix borda"></span>
            </article>'; 
    }              
    $conn->close(); 
?>
```

Hopefully, I have described the problem correctly.

Comment: every modal has the same `id=myModal`. This is why bootstrap will always open the same. Give them unique ids and adjust the opening button accordingly to the same ids (in data-target)

Comment: I can use the id of the shop from the database?

Comment: yes, that would be best.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As someone has commented, you are giving every modal the same ID, and every button the same target. You need to give them unique ones. Declare a counter just before your while loop, say `$i = 0`;

```
$i = 0;
while ( ...
```

Change:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

to:

```
 <div class="modal fade" id="myModal_<? echo $i; ?>" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
```

and change the button, from:

```
echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal"> Show more </button>';
```

to:

```
echo'<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal_' .$i .'"> Show more </button>';
```

and increment `$i` before your while loop closes, using `$i++`:

```
    ...
    $i++;
}
```